# Oracle: Complex Query runs very fast as Query, very slow as View

Tags: oracle, performance, indexing, view

I have a View, based on a UNION ALL of several SELECTs, each using UNPIVOT,  which for a particular case runs very slow when querying the View, but very fast when querying the underlying Query.

Here is the Explain Plan for the query on the View:

```
select * from MY_SLOW_VIEW where SourceID='1234567890';
```

[image: Slow View]

Compared to the Explain Plan on the underlying query:

```
select * from (select ... ) where SourceID='1234567890';
```

[image: Fast Query]

Now that Looks like when using the View the indexes arent working.
I have tried adding INDEX Hints in the individual selects that are Union all'd together, but that had no effect.

(That SourceID is the oid from several tables displayed as a String.)

Here is the code (paraphrased):

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE FORCE VIEW "MY_SLOW_VIEW" (
      "SOURCEID", 
      "ACTIONPARAMETERKEY", 
      "ACTIONPARAMETERVALUE", 
      "UPDDAT") 

    AS

    SELECT 
       cast(sourceid as varchar2(50)) as sourceid,
       actionparameterkey,
       actionparametervalue, 
       upddat  

    FROM (

    (   SELECT 
            sourceid,
            actionparameterkey,
            to_char(actionparametervalue) as actionparametervalue, 
            upddat
        FROM 
        (   select 
                table1.oid as sourceid, 
                table1.upddat as upddat,  
                to_char(table1.status) as status, 
                to_char(table1.typ) as typ,     
            from table1)
            UNPIVOT (actionparametervalue for actionparameterkey in (
                    typ as 'policyType', 
                    status as 'policyStatus')
        )
    )

    UNION ALL

    (   SELECT 
            sourceid,
            actionparameterkey,
            to_char(actionparametervalue) as actionparametervalue, 
            upddat
        FROM 
        (   select 
                table2.oid as sourceid, 
                table2.upddat as upddat,  
                to_char(table2.productKey) as productKey, 
                to_char(table2.contractID) as contractId,     
            from table2)
        UNPIVOT (actionparametervalue for actionparameterkey in (
                    productKey as 'productKey', 
                    contractId as 'contractId')
        )
    )

    UNION ALL

            [snip]

    )
```

Does anyone have any hints as either how to make the Indexes work in the view, or any other hints regarding what the problem might be?

Thanks

[edit - adding Plan-table Output, as suggested by kordirko]

First .. the raw query

```
"PLAN_TABLE_OUTPUT"
"Plan hash value: 2498531538"
" "
"----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------"
"| Id  | Operation                             | Name                         | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |"
"----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------"
"|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT                      |                              |     6 |   624 |    81   (7)| 00:00:01 |"
"|   1 |  VIEW                                 |                              |     6 |   624 |    81   (7)| 00:00:01 |"
"|   2 |   UNION-ALL                           |                              |       |       |            |          |"
"|   3 |    HASH UNIQUE                        |                              |     1 |    79 |    36   (3)| 00:00:01 |"
"|*  4 |     VIEW                              |                              |    21 |  1659 |    35   (0)| 00:00:01 |"
"|   5 |      UNPIVOT                          |                              |       |       |            |          |"
"|   6 |       NESTED LOOPS                    |                              |     3 |   498 |     5   (0)| 00:00:01 |"
"|   7 |        NESTED LOOPS                   |                              |     3 |   498 |     5   (0)| 00:00:01 |"
"|   8 |         NESTED LOOPS                  |                              |     3 |   378 |     4   (0)| 00:00:01 |"
"|   9 |          NESTED LOOPS                 |                              |     3 |   339 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |"
"|  10 |           NESTED LOOPS                |                              |     1 |    99 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |"
"|  11 |            TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID| PLANANSCHLUSS                |     1 |    46 |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |"
"|* 12 |             INDEX UNIQUE SCAN         | SYS_C0012952                 |     1 |       |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |"
"|  13 |            TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID| ANSCHLUSS                    |     1 |    53 |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |"
"|* 14 |             INDEX UNIQUE SCAN         | SYS_C0012832                 |     1 |       |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |"
"|  15 |           TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID | VERSICHERTER                 |     3 |    42 |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |"
"|* 16 |            INDEX RANGE SCAN           | IX6_VERSICHERTER             |     3 |       |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |"
"|* 17 |          TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID  | PARTNERROLLE                 |     1 |    13 |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |"
"|* 18 |           INDEX UNIQUE SCAN           | SYS_C0012947                 |     1 |       |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |"
"|* 19 |         INDEX RANGE SCAN              | IX5_NATPERSON                |     1 |       |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |"
"|  20 |        TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID    | NATPERSON                    |     1 |    40 |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |"
"|  21 |    NESTED LOOPS                       |                              |     1 |    24 |     4   (0)| 00:00:01 |"
"|  22 |     NESTED LOOPS                      |                              |     1 |    24 |     4   (0)| 00:00:01 |"
"|* 23 |      TABLE ACCESS FULL                | INVESTITION                  |     1 |    14 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |"
"|* 24 |      INDEX UNIQUE SCAN                | INVESTITION_AUFTRAG_PK       |     1 |       |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |"
"|* 25 |     TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID       | INVESTITION_AUFTRAG          |     1 |    10 |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |"
"|* 26 |    FILTER                             |                              |       |       |            |          |"
"|* 27 |     TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID       | PLANANSCHLUSS                |     1 |    40 |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |"
"|* 28 |      INDEX UNIQUE SCAN                | SYS_C0012952                 |     1 |       |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |"
"|* 29 |     TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID       | PLANANSCHLUSS                |     1 |    37 |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |"
"|* 30 |      INDEX RANGE SCAN                 | IX5_PLA_VERSICHERTERID       |     1 |       |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |"
"|  31 |    HASH UNIQUE                        |                              |     2 |    98 |     5  (20)| 00:00:01 |"
"|* 32 |     VIEW                              |                              |     2 |    98 |     4   (0)| 00:00:01 |"
"|  33 |      UNPIVOT                          |                              |       |       |            |          |"
"|* 34 |       FILTER                          |                              |       |       |            |          |"
"|  35 |        NESTED LOOPS OUTER             |                              |     1 |    75 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |"
"|* 36 |         TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID   | MUTBELEG_AKTIVE_STAND        |     1 |    34 |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |"
"|* 37 |          INDEX RANGE SCAN             | IX1_MUTB_A_PLAFKOID_CALCDATE |    10 |       |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |"
"|* 38 |         TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID   | MUTBELEG_AKTIVE_STAND        |     1 |    41 |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |"
"|* 39 |          INDEX RANGE SCAN             | IX1_MUTB_A_PLAFKOID_CALCDATE |    10 |       |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |"
"|  40 |    HASH UNIQUE                        |                              |     1 |    79 |    31   (4)| 00:00:01 |"
"|* 41 |     VIEW                              |                              |     6 |   474 |    30   (0)| 00:00:01 |"
"|  42 |      UNPIVOT                          |                              |       |       |            |          |"
"|  43 |       NESTED LOOPS                    |                              |     1 |   159 |     5   (0)| 00:00:01 |"
"|  44 |        NESTED LOOPS                   |                              |     1 |   119 |     4   (0)| 00:00:01 |"
"|  45 |         NESTED LOOPS                  |                              |     1 |   106 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |"
"|  46 |          NESTED LOOPS                 |                              |     1 |    90 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |"
"|  47 |           TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID | RV_POLICE                    |     1 |    37 |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |"
"|* 48 |            INDEX UNIQUE SCAN          | PK_RV_POLICE                 |     1 |       |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |"
"|  49 |           TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID | ANSCHLUSS                    |     1 |    53 |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |"
"|* 50 |            INDEX UNIQUE SCAN          | SYS_C0012832                 |     1 |       |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |"
"|  51 |          TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID  | RV_LEISTUNGSFALL             |     1 |    16 |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |"
"|* 52 |           INDEX UNIQUE SCAN           | PK_RV_LEISTUNGSFALL          |     1 |       |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |"
"|* 53 |         TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID   | PARTNERROLLE                 |     1 |    13 |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |"
"|* 54 |          INDEX UNIQUE SCAN            | SYS_C0012947                 |     1 |       |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |"
"|  55 |        TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID    | NATPERSON                    |     1 |    40 |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |"
"|* 56 |         INDEX RANGE SCAN              | IX5_NATPERSON                |     1 |       |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |"
"|* 57 |    VIEW                               |                              |     1 |    91 |     2  (50)| 00:00:01 |"
"|* 58 |     TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID       | RV_LEISTUNGBASIS             |     1 |    42 |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |"
"|* 59 |      INDEX RANGE SCAN                 | IX1_RV_LEISTUNGBASIS         |     1 |       |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |"
"|  60 |     HASH UNIQUE                       |                              |     1 |    35 |     2  (50)| 00:00:01 |"
"|  61 |      TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID      | RV_LEISTUNGBASIS             |     1 |    35 |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |"
"|* 62 |       INDEX RANGE SCAN                | IX1_RV_LEISTUNGBASIS         |     1 |       |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |"
"----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------"
" "
"Predicate Information (identified by operation id):"
"---------------------------------------------------"
" "
"   4 - filter(""unpivot_view_069"".""ACTIONPARAMETERVALUE"" IS NOT NULL)"
"  12 - access(""PA"".""OID""=3505032127)"
"  14 - access(""PA"".""ANSCHLUSSFKOID""=""A"".""OID"")"
"  16 - access(""PA"".""VERSICHERTERFKID""=""V"".""ID"")"
"  17 - filter(""PR"".""NATPERSONFKID"" IS NOT NULL)"
"  18 - access(""V"".""ROLLEVERSICHERTERFKOID""=""PR"".""OID"")"
"  19 - access(""PR"".""NATPERSONFKID""=""NP"".""ID"")"
"  23 - filter(""INV"".""PLANANSCHLUSSFKOID""=:B1)"
"  24 - access(""INV"".""AUFTRAGFKOID""=""INV_AUF"".""OID"")"
"  25 - filter(""INV_AUF"".""ISBESTAETIG""=0)"
"  26 - filter(CASE  WHEN  EXISTS (SELECT 0 FROM ""PLANANSCHLUSS"" ""PA2"" WHERE ""PA2"".""VERSICHERTERFKID""=:B1 AND "
"              ""PA2"".""ANSCHLUSSFKOID""=:B2 AND NVL(""PA2"".""UPDDAT"",""PA2"".""CREDAT"")>NVL(:B3,:B4)) THEN 0 ELSE 1 END =1)"
"  27 - filter(""PA"".""ISIVA""=1)"
"  28 - access(""PA"".""OID""=3505032127)"
"       filter(CASE  WHEN  EXISTS (SELECT 0 FROM ""INVESTITION_AUFTRAG"" ""INV_AUF"",""INVESTITION"" ""INV"" WHERE "
"              ""INV"".""PLANANSCHLUSSFKOID""=:B1 AND ""INV"".""AUFTRAGFKOID""=""INV_AUF"".""OID"" AND ""INV_AUF"".""ISBESTAETIG""=0) THEN "
"              '1' ELSE '0' END  IS NOT NULL)"
"  29 - filter(""PA2"".""ANSCHLUSSFKOID""=:B1 AND NVL(""PA2"".""UPDDAT"",""PA2"".""CREDAT"")>NVL(:B2,:B3))"
"  30 - access(""PA2"".""VERSICHERTERFKID""=:B1)"
"  32 - filter(""unpivot_view_079"".""ACTIONPARAMETERVALUE"" IS NOT NULL)"
"  34 - filter(""MAS2"".""OID"" IS NULL)"
"  36 - filter(""MAS"".""ISTAKTUELLSTER""=1 AND CASE NVL(""MAS"".""PRODUKTSUBCD"",""MAS"".""PRODUKTCD"") WHEN 'na' THEN "
"              ""MAS"".""PRODUKTCD"" ELSE NVL(""MAS"".""PRODUKTSUBCD"",""MAS"".""PRODUKTCD"") END  IS NOT NULL)"
"  37 - access(""MAS"".""PLANANSCHLUSSFKOID""=3505032127)"
"  38 - filter(""MAS2"".""ISTAKTUELLSTER""(+)=1 AND ""MAS2"".""CREDAT""(+)>""MAS"".""CREDAT"" AND "
"              NVL(""MAS2"".""PLANMERKMALCD2""(+),'ERWP')=NVL(""MAS"".""PLANMERKMALCD2"",'ERWP') AND CASE "
"              NVL(""MAS"".""PRODUKTSUBCD"",""MAS"".""PRODUKTCD"") WHEN 'na' THEN ""MAS"".""PRODUKTCD"" ELSE "
"              NVL(""MAS"".""PRODUKTSUBCD"",""MAS"".""PRODUKTCD"") END =CASE NVL(""MAS2"".""PRODUKTSUBCD""(+),""MAS2"".""PRODUKTCD""(+)) "
"              WHEN 'na' THEN ""MAS2"".""PRODUKTCD""(+) ELSE NVL(""MAS2"".""PRODUKTSUBCD""(+),""MAS2"".""PRODUKTCD""(+)) END )"
"  39 - access(""MAS2"".""PLANANSCHLUSSFKOID""(+)=3505032127)"
"  41 - filter(""unpivot_view_111"".""ACTIONPARAMETERVALUE"" IS NOT NULL)"
"  48 - access(""POL"".""OID""=3505032127)"
"  50 - access(""POL"".""X_ANSCHLUSSFKOID""=""A"".""OID"")"
"  52 - access(""POL"".""RV_LEISTUNGSFALLFKOID""=""LF"".""OID"")"
"  53 - filter(""PR"".""NATPERSONFKID"" IS NOT NULL)"
"  54 - access(""LF"".""ROLLERENTNERFKOID""=""PR"".""OID"")"
"  56 - access(""PR"".""NATPERSONFKID""=""NP"".""ID"")"
"  57 - filter(""from$_subquery$_028"".""ISTAKTUELLSTER""=1)"
"  58 - filter(""RV2"".""LEISTUNGCD""=:B1 AND NVL(""RV2"".""UPDDAT"",""RV2"".""CREDAT"")>NVL(:B2,:B3))"
"  59 - access(""RV2"".""RV_POLICEFKOID""=:B1)"
"  62 - access(""RV"".""RV_POLICEFKOID""=3505032127)"
```

2nd .. for the query on the View

```
"PLAN_TABLE_OUTPUT"
"Plan hash value: 2116722895"
" "
"----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------"
"| Id  | Operation                             | Name                         | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |"
"----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------"
"|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT                      |                              |     6 |   624 |   199K  (1)| 00:39:50 |"
"|   1 |  VIEW                                 |                              |     6 |   624 |   199K  (1)| 00:39:50 |"
"|   2 |   UNION-ALL                           |                              |       |       |            |          |"
"|   3 |    HASH UNIQUE                        |                              |     1 |    79 | 20007   (1)| 00:04:01 |"
"|*  4 |     VIEW                              |                              |    21 |  1659 | 20006   (1)| 00:04:01 |"
"|   5 |      UNPIVOT                          |                              |       |       |            |          |"
"|   6 |       NESTED LOOPS                    |                              |     3 |   498 |  2858   (1)| 00:00:35 |"
"|   7 |        NESTED LOOPS                   |                              |     3 |   498 |  2858   (1)| 00:00:35 |"
"|   8 |         NESTED LOOPS                  |                              |     3 |   378 |  2857   (1)| 00:00:35 |"
"|   9 |          NESTED LOOPS                 |                              |     3 |   339 |  2856   (1)| 00:00:35 |"
"|  10 |           NESTED LOOPS                |                              |     1 |    99 |  2855   (1)| 00:00:35 |"
"|* 11 |            TABLE ACCESS FULL          | PLANANSCHLUSS                |     1 |    46 |  2854   (1)| 00:00:35 |"
"|  12 |            TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID| ANSCHLUSS                    |     1 |    53 |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |"
"|* 13 |             INDEX UNIQUE SCAN         | SYS_C0012832                 |     1 |       |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |"
"|  14 |           TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID | VERSICHERTER                 |     3 |    42 |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |"
"|* 15 |            INDEX RANGE SCAN           | IX6_VERSICHERTER             |     3 |       |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |"
"|* 16 |          TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID  | PARTNERROLLE                 |     1 |    13 |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |"
"|* 17 |           INDEX UNIQUE SCAN           | SYS_C0012947                 |     1 |       |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |"
"|* 18 |         INDEX RANGE SCAN              | IX5_NATPERSON                |     1 |       |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |"
"|  19 |        TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID    | NATPERSON                    |     1 |    40 |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |"
"|  20 |    NESTED LOOPS                       |                              |     1 |    24 |     4   (0)| 00:00:01 |"
"|  21 |     NESTED LOOPS                      |                              |     1 |    24 |     4   (0)| 00:00:01 |"
"|* 22 |      TABLE ACCESS FULL                | INVESTITION                  |     1 |    14 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |"
"|* 23 |      INDEX UNIQUE SCAN                | INVESTITION_AUFTRAG_PK       |     1 |       |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |"
"|* 24 |     TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID       | INVESTITION_AUFTRAG          |     1 |    10 |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |"
"|  25 |    HASH UNIQUE                        |                              |     1 |    40 |  2865   (1)| 00:00:35 |"
"|* 26 |     FILTER                            |                              |       |       |            |          |"
"|* 27 |      TABLE ACCESS FULL                | PLANANSCHLUSS                |     1 |    40 |  2859   (1)| 00:00:35 |"
"|* 28 |      TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID      | PLANANSCHLUSS                |     1 |    37 |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |"
"|* 29 |       INDEX RANGE SCAN                | IX5_PLA_VERSICHERTERID       |     1 |       |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |"
"|  30 |    HASH UNIQUE                        |                              |     2 |    98 |   173K  (1)| 00:34:43 |"
"|* 31 |     VIEW                              |                              |     2 |    98 |   173K  (1)| 00:34:43 |"
"|  32 |      UNPIVOT                          |                              |       |       |            |          |"
"|* 33 |       FILTER                          |                              |       |       |            |          |"
"|  34 |        NESTED LOOPS OUTER             |                              |     1 |    75 | 86771   (1)| 00:17:22 |"
"|* 35 |         TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID   | MUTBELEG_AKTIVE_STAND        |     1 |    34 | 86770   (1)| 00:17:22 |"
"|* 36 |          INDEX RANGE SCAN             | IX5_MUTB_A_ISTAKTUELLSTER    |  2381K|       |   590   (1)| 00:00:08 |"
"|* 37 |         TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID   | MUTBELEG_AKTIVE_STAND        | 23817 |   953K|     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |"
"|* 38 |          INDEX RANGE SCAN             | IX1_MUTB_A_PLAFKOID_CALCDATE |    10 |       |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |"
"|  39 |    HASH UNIQUE                        |                              |     1 |    79 |  2330   (1)| 00:00:28 |"
"|* 40 |     VIEW                              |                              |     6 |   474 |  2329   (1)| 00:00:28 |"
"|  41 |      UNPIVOT                          |                              |       |       |            |          |"
"|  42 |       NESTED LOOPS                    |                              |     1 |   159 |   388   (1)| 00:00:05 |"
"|  43 |        NESTED LOOPS                   |                              |     1 |   159 |   388   (1)| 00:00:05 |"
"|  44 |         NESTED LOOPS                  |                              |     1 |   119 |   387   (1)| 00:00:05 |"
"|  45 |          NESTED LOOPS                 |                              |     1 |    66 |   386   (1)| 00:00:05 |"
"|  46 |           NESTED LOOPS                |                              |     1 |    53 |   385   (1)| 00:00:05 |"
"|* 47 |            TABLE ACCESS FULL          | RV_POLICE                    |     1 |    37 |   384   (1)| 00:00:05 |"
"|  48 |            TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID| RV_LEISTUNGSFALL             |     1 |    16 |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |"
"|* 49 |             INDEX UNIQUE SCAN         | PK_RV_LEISTUNGSFALL          |     1 |       |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |"
"|* 50 |           TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID | PARTNERROLLE                 |     1 |    13 |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |"
"|* 51 |            INDEX UNIQUE SCAN          | SYS_C0012947                 |     1 |       |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |"
"|  52 |          TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID  | ANSCHLUSS                    |     1 |    53 |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |"
"|* 53 |           INDEX UNIQUE SCAN           | SYS_C0012832                 |     1 |       |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |"
"|* 54 |         INDEX RANGE SCAN              | IX5_NATPERSON                |     1 |       |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |"
"|  55 |        TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID    | NATPERSON                    |     1 |    40 |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |"
"|* 56 |    VIEW                               |                              |     1 |    91 |   385   (1)| 00:00:05 |"
"|* 57 |     TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID       | RV_LEISTUNGBASIS             |     1 |    42 |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |"
"|* 58 |      INDEX RANGE SCAN                 | IX1_RV_LEISTUNGBASIS         |     1 |       |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |"
"|  59 |     HASH UNIQUE                       |                              |     1 |    35 |   385   (1)| 00:00:05 |"
"|* 60 |      TABLE ACCESS FULL                | RV_LEISTUNGBASIS             |     1 |    35 |   384   (1)| 00:00:05 |"
"----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------"
" "
"Predicate Information (identified by operation id):"
"---------------------------------------------------"
" "
"   4 - filter(""unpivot_view_070"".""ACTIONPARAMETERVALUE"" IS NOT NULL)"
"  11 - filter(CAST(""PA"".""OID"" AS varchar2(50))='3505032127')"
"  13 - access(""PA"".""ANSCHLUSSFKOID""=""A"".""OID"")"
"  15 - access(""PA"".""VERSICHERTERFKID""=""V"".""ID"")"
"  16 - filter(""PR"".""NATPERSONFKID"" IS NOT NULL)"
"  17 - access(""V"".""ROLLEVERSICHERTERFKOID""=""PR"".""OID"")"
"  18 - access(""PR"".""NATPERSONFKID""=""NP"".""ID"")"
"  22 - filter(""INV"".""PLANANSCHLUSSFKOID""=:B1)"
"  23 - access(""INV"".""AUFTRAGFKOID""=""INV_AUF"".""OID"")"
"  24 - filter(""INV_AUF"".""ISBESTAETIG""=0)"
"  26 - filter(CASE  WHEN  EXISTS (SELECT 0 FROM SL_PAV_BEST.""INVESTITION_AUFTRAG"" "
"              ""INV_AUF"",SL_PAV_BEST.""INVESTITION"" ""INV"" WHERE ""INV"".""PLANANSCHLUSSFKOID""=:B1 AND "
"              ""INV"".""AUFTRAGFKOID""=""INV_AUF"".""OID"" AND ""INV_AUF"".""ISBESTAETIG""=0) THEN '1' ELSE '0' END  IS NOT NULL AND "
"              CASE  WHEN  EXISTS (SELECT 0 FROM SL_PAV_BEST.""PLANANSCHLUSS"" ""PA2"" WHERE ""PA2"".""VERSICHERTERFKID""=:B2 AND "
"              ""PA2"".""ANSCHLUSSFKOID""=:B3 AND NVL(""PA2"".""UPDDAT"",""PA2"".""CREDAT"")>NVL(:B4,:B5)) THEN 0 ELSE 1 END =1)"
"  27 - filter(""PA"".""ISIVA""=1 AND CAST(""PA"".""OID"" AS varchar2(50))='3505032127')"
"  28 - filter(""PA2"".""ANSCHLUSSFKOID""=:B1 AND NVL(""PA2"".""UPDDAT"",""PA2"".""CREDAT"")>NVL(:B2,:B3))"
"  29 - access(""PA2"".""VERSICHERTERFKID""=:B1)"
"  31 - filter(""unpivot_view_080"".""ACTIONPARAMETERVALUE"" IS NOT NULL)"
"  33 - filter(""MAS2"".""OID"" IS NULL)"
"  35 - filter(CAST(""MAS"".""PLANANSCHLUSSFKOID"" AS varchar2(50))='3505032127' AND CASE "
"              NVL(""MAS"".""PRODUKTSUBCD"",""MAS"".""PRODUKTCD"") WHEN 'na' THEN ""MAS"".""PRODUKTCD"" ELSE "
"              NVL(""MAS"".""PRODUKTSUBCD"",""MAS"".""PRODUKTCD"") END  IS NOT NULL)"
"  36 - access(""MAS"".""ISTAKTUELLSTER""=1)"
"  37 - filter(""MAS2"".""ISTAKTUELLSTER""(+)=1 AND ""MAS2"".""CREDAT""(+)>""MAS"".""CREDAT"" AND "
"              NVL(""MAS2"".""PLANMERKMALCD2""(+),'ERWP')=NVL(""MAS"".""PLANMERKMALCD2"",'ERWP') AND CASE "
"              NVL(""MAS"".""PRODUKTSUBCD"",""MAS"".""PRODUKTCD"") WHEN 'na' THEN ""MAS"".""PRODUKTCD"" ELSE "
"              NVL(""MAS"".""PRODUKTSUBCD"",""MAS"".""PRODUKTCD"") END =CASE NVL(""MAS2"".""PRODUKTSUBCD""(+),""MAS2"".""PRODUKTCD""(+)) "
"              WHEN 'na' THEN ""MAS2"".""PRODUKTCD""(+) ELSE NVL(""MAS2"".""PRODUKTSUBCD""(+),""MAS2"".""PRODUKTCD""(+)) END )"
"  38 - access(""MAS2"".""PLANANSCHLUSSFKOID""(+)=""MAS"".""PLANANSCHLUSSFKOID"")"
"  40 - filter(""unpivot_view_112"".""ACTIONPARAMETERVALUE"" IS NOT NULL)"
"  47 - filter(CAST(""POL"".""OID"" AS varchar2(50))='3505032127')"
"  49 - access(""POL"".""RV_LEISTUNGSFALLFKOID""=""LF"".""OID"")"
"  50 - filter(""PR"".""NATPERSONFKID"" IS NOT NULL)"
"  51 - access(""LF"".""ROLLERENTNERFKOID""=""PR"".""OID"")"
"  53 - access(""POL"".""X_ANSCHLUSSFKOID""=""A"".""OID"")"
"  54 - access(""PR"".""NATPERSONFKID""=""NP"".""ID"")"
"  56 - filter(""from$_subquery$_029"".""ISTAKTUELLSTER""=1)"
"  57 - filter(""RV2"".""LEISTUNGCD""=:B1 AND NVL(""RV2"".""UPDDAT"",""RV2"".""CREDAT"")>NVL(:B2,:B3))"
"  58 - access(""RV2"".""RV_POLICEFKOID""=:B1)"
"  60 - filter(CAST(""RV"".""RV_POLICEFKOID"" AS varchar2(50))='3505032127')"
```

Comment: Please run `EXPLAIN PLAN FOR query` and then `SELECT * FROM table(DBMS_XPLAN.Display)` for the first, and then for the second query , and append results of these queres to the question **as a text** (not a bitmap). Please append the whole result (togehter with "predicate information" printed at the bottom of the query plan.

Comment: I added the Information, as you suggested kordirko. Thank you for your Input.

Comment: do you have actual statistics? is the view query fatster with `RULE` hint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compare these rows from both plans:
The upper plan - predicate information:

```
"  12 - access(""PA"".""OID""=3505032127)"
"  28 - access(""PA"".""OID""=3505032127)"
"  48 - access(""POL"".""OID""=3505032127)"
"  62 - access(""RV"".""RV_POLICEFKOID""=3505032127)"
```

and the bottom plan - the view:

```
"  11 - filter(CAST(""PA"".""OID"" AS varchar2(50))='3505032127')"
"  27 - filter(""PA"".""ISIVA""=1 AND CAST(""PA"".""OID"" AS varchar2(50))='3505032127')"
"  35 - filter(CAST(""MAS"".""PLANANSCHLUSSFKOID"" AS varchar2(50))='3505032127' AND CASE "
"  47 - filter(CAST(""POL"".""OID"" AS varchar2(50))='3505032127')"
"  60 - filter(CAST(""RV"".""RV_POLICEFKOID"" AS varchar2(50))='3505032127')"
```

---

It's hard to say without looking at the exact view definition, but there is something in this view that forces a cast of table columns to varchar2, preventing the view from using of indexes, while the raw query uses a direct number `3505032127` (not a varchar).
You can try to use a number literal in your query:

```
select * from MY_SLOW_VIEW where SourceID=1234567890;
```

instead of varchar2 literal

```
select * from MY_SLOW_VIEW where SourceID='1234567890';
```

---

**EDIT ---------**

---

Sorry, I'din't notice this in the view definition:

```
  SELECT 
       cast(sourceid as varchar2(50)) as sourceid,
```

this is a root of the error. Remove the cast of `sourceid` to varchar, this should improve the query.

Comment: Cheers. I also noticed that, and have been checking it out. 

There is an explicit cast to varchar2 in the query output. That is a wish from the customer, and this is a query that has been in use for years. However in this case it is now clear it causes problems. Calling the query on its own, even with the cast, works fine, but as a View it doesnt. 

For a test i removed the cast, and that solves the Problem. I will have to discuss this with the customer tomorrow. Might need to add a new field 'SourceID_desc' as varchar2 for their Output, but keep the SourceID as a Number for querying.